# Using libraries with C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, barcode, qmake

I am trying to use a library to generate barcode images inside a Qt/C++ app.

I've been looking at ZINT and ZXING, but I don't understand how would I use them inside my code.

If I download and compile the library, how do I call it afterwards? Could I set up the Qt makefile to compile it for the desired platform?

Thanks, and sorry for the broad question, I'm not very experienced in C++ projects.

Answer (score 0):

In QT you usually include 3rd party libraries through the .pro file. Use the [LIBS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) variable to tell QT where to find it.

Example lines from the QT [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html):

```
TARGET = MyQtApp

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += 3rdparty/CatWhisperer/include

SOURCES += src/main.cpp

LIBS += -L"3rdparty/CatWhisperer/lib" -lCatWhisperer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt Creator, you can add libraries to your .pro by using a wizard provided by the IDE. Right-click your project in the project browser, click `Add library...` and, then, follow the wizard.

More details here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html